# Java - How to convert type collection into ArrayList?

Tags: java, collections

```
public class MyGraph<V,E> extends SparseMultigraph<V,E>{
    private ArrayList<MyNode> myNodeList;

    public MyNode getNode(int nodeId){
        myNodeList = new ArrayList<MyNode>();
        myNodeList = (ArrayList<MyNode>)this.getVertices();
        int i;
```

The following are the error msg:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection cannot be cast to
>   java.util.ArrayList...

Can anyone help?

Comment: Loop through and just add the nodes.

Comment: Please post more code, at the very least the declarations & initializations of all participating elements. Ideally, post a small program that compiles & runs and demonstrates your problem. Simplifying your program in that way will often already point you to the solution.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As other people have mentioned, ArrayList has a constructor that takes a collection of items, and adds all of them.  Here's the documentation:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29

So you need to do:

```
ArrayList<MyNode> myNodeList = new ArrayList<MyNode>(this.getVertices());
```

However, in another comment you said that was giving you a compiler error. It looks like your class MyGraph is a **generic** class. And so getVertices() actually returns type V, not type myNode.

I think your code should look like this:

```
public V getNode(int nodeId){
        ArrayList<V> myNodeList = new ArrayList<V>(this.getVertices());
        return myNodeList(nodeId);
}
```

But, that said it's a very inefficient way to extract a node.  What you might want to do is store the nodes in a binary tree, then when you get a request for the nth node, you do a binary search.

Comment: Beware that it returns a shallow copy. Not a reference to the list actually.

Comment: @Chad Okere how is it possible to arraylist and not possible into a list?

Answer (score 26):

Try this code

**Convert ArrayList to Collection**

```
ArrayList<User> usersArrayList = new ArrayList<User>();

Collection<User> userCollection = new HashSet<User>(usersArrayList);
```

**Convert Collection to ArrayList**

```
Collection<User> userCollection = new HashSet<User>(usersArrayList);

List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(userCollection);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public <E> List<E> collectionToList(Collection<E> collection)
{
    return (collection instanceof List) ? (List<E>) collection : new ArrayList<E>(collection);
}
```

Use the above method for converting the collection to list

Answer (score 6):

The following code will fail:

```
List<String> will_fail = (List<String>)Collections.unmodifiableCollection(new ArrayList<String>());
```

This instead will work:

```
List<String> will_work = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.unmodifiableCollection(new ArrayList<String>()));
```

Answer (score 1):

More information needed for a definitive answer, but this code

```
myNodeList = (ArrayList<MyNode>)this.getVertices();
```

will *only* work if `this.getVertices()` returns a  (subtype of) `List<MyNode>`. If it is a different collection (like your Exception seems to indicate), you want to use

```
new ArrayList<MyNode>(this.getVertices())
```

This will work as long as a Collection type is returned by getVertices.

Comment: It returns a colletion type...
but this one
new ArrayList<MyNode>(this.getVertices()) 
does not work..